# Why can't I access my html-elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, progressive-web-apps

So, I'm sitting here for quite some time now, trying to figure out how to access my Login-Forms input elements.

I am writing a PWA based on the polymer starter kit, this is my html-code:

```
<template id="loginTemplate"> 
    <style>
        //removed styles for better overview
    </style>
    <hgroup>
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </hgroup>
    <form id="loginForm">
        <div class="group">
            <input id="username" type="email"><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input id="password" type="text"><span class="bar"></span>
            <label>Passwort</label>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="button buttonBlue" onclick="login()">Login
          <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
        </button>
    </form>
</template>
```

And this is my javascript(written in the same HTML file):

```
<script>
    // Define the element's API using an ES2015 class
    class MyLogin extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'my-login'; }

    }


    var login=function()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        //var temp = document.querySelector('#loginTemplate');
        //var formElements = temp.content.querySelectorAll("form")[0].elements;
        var formElements = document.getElementById("loginForm").elements;

        var pass=formElements["password"];
        var mail=formElements["username"];
        //have already tried:
        //var pass=document.getElementById("password");
        //var pass=document.getElementById("username");
        //and
        //var pass=$("#password").val();
        //var pass=$("#username").val();

        client.login('http://localhost:50253/Token', pass, mail, function() { 

            window.alert("logged in!")

            client.get('http://localhost:50253/api/Task', function(response){
                window.alert(response); 
            });

        });
    }

    customElements.define(MyLogin.is, MyLogin);
</script>
```

The Problem is, whenever I try to use the methode "getElementById", I get an undefined element back:

f.e. if I would use `document.getElementById("loginForm").elements;`

I would get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of null

EDIT: i don't know if it matters but i wanted to point out that the WHOLE html file is inside a dom-module

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Use jQuery.  DOM manipulation is what it was born for.

Comment: @duffymo that won't help in this case; all the code attempts is a simple `getElementById()`.

Comment: If you use elements, your inputs need "name" attributes, but that does not matter when you have null.

Comment: Are you actually rendering/binding the template?

Comment: The HTML you posted has all that content inside a `<template>` element. Until the markup inside the template is actually rendered by something, it's not actually part of the DOM.

Comment: yes the template is rendered, i am sure of that because i test my code by pressing the login button to call the login methode: https://gyazo.com/aca0c44ea80e9d2f00bda794f9d2ef6b

Comment: Make sure the JS is running after the DOM has loaded?

Comment: Yes, the dom has to load for me to be able to press the login button and call that method, unless i missunderstood something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's inside `<template>` is part of the shadow dom, and can't be accessed the same way as accessing 'regular' Dom.

In your case (Polymer v2) you need to do

```
var formElements = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#loginForm').elements;
```

**EDIT:**

Now I realized... function login has to be inside the class, you have it outside. Should be something like this:

```
class MyLogin extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() { return 'my-login'; }

      // the function is inside the class
      login() {
        // define whatever this function does...
      }

}

customElements.define(MyLogin.is, MyLogin);
```

Comment: this looked very promising, unfortunately it didn't work for me, when using this.shadowRoot it returned undefined, placing a watch on this.ShadowRoot returned a function

Comment: I have implemented the changes, yet i ran into the same problem: when using this.shadowRoot it returns undefined, placing a watch on this.ShadowRoot returns a function, should i post my updated code?

Comment: Yes please. And also post what `this.shadowRoot` function returns

Comment: Ok nvm, i have tried the same exact solution again and it worked, thank you very much!